# Do I need to use "e = e ? e : window.event;" with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw in some no jQuery code this part of code inside event:

```
e = e ? e : window.event;
```

I use jQuery and I am wondering if I am safe to remove this part of code:

```
jQuery(document).mouseout(function(e){
  console.log(e)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need to use “e = e ? e : window.event;” with jQuery?

No, you do not. jQuery handles the global `event` vs. argument thing for you (along with other differences in the event objects). jQuery's [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) is just a shortcut for `on("mouseout"`, see [the `on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for details about how jQuery normalizes events for you. Your second code snippet is fine (other than missing the closing `)`, and you probably want a `;` as well).